# How to setup a cross platform project with Next.js and React Native

Tags: react-native, next.js

I need to create a cross platform project with 99% shared UI between mobile app and mobile browser. I also need the hybrid render mechanic provided by Next.js. How should I setup my projects?

option 1:
a single project with different build variants, how do I mix nextjs and React Native into one project?

option 2:
a React-Native project and a Next.js project serve as the UI implementations and they all import a shared abstract app project which contains UI-less logics such as abstract event listeners and states.